# Angular RXJS Make multiple http parallel calls after first request get done

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects, fork-join

After receiving the initial request response, I need to perform three parallel requests in my ngrx Effect.
I implemented the following, however when I inspect it using the network tab, all three requests are queued. and all queries are executed sequentially.

1. I WANT TO MAKE THREE PARALLEL REQUESTS.
2. HOW TO VERIFY WHETHER A FORK JOIN RESULT IS UNDEFINED OR NOT.

   ```
   fetchDataTotallyWhenUserLogIn$ = createEffect(() => {
       return this.actions$.pipe(
         ofType(fetchDefaultSitePerUser),
         switchMap(() => {
           return FIRST REQUEST (params)
             .pipe(
               this.startWithTap(() => this.store.dispatch(setLoadingSpinner({showLoading: true}))),
               filter(firstReqResponse=> firstReqResponse!== undefined),
               tap(firstReqResponse => {
                 if (firstReqResponse === null) {
                   throw "The user's default site has not been assigned."
                 } else {
                   sessionStorage.setItem(Foo, JSON.stringify(firstReqResponse));
                 }
               }),
               map(firstReqResponse => firstReqResponse),
           concatMap(firstReqResponse =>
            //I NEED MAKE FOLLOWING REQUESTS AS PARALLEL
             forkJoin([
               PARALLEL_REQUEST_01(firstReqResponse ),
               PARALLEL_REQUEST_02(firstReqResponse ),
               PARALLEL_REQUEST_03(firstReqResponse )
             ]).pipe(
               filter(response => response !== undefined),
               map(([PARALLEL_REQUEST_01_RESP, PARALLEL_REQUEST_02_RESP, PARALLEL_REQUEST_03_RESP]) => {
                 return LastAction(
                   {
                     a: PARALLEL_REQUEST_01_RESP,
                     b: PARALLEL_REQUEST_02_RESP,
                     c: PARALLEL_REQUEST_03_RESP,
                     d: firstReqResponse 
                   })
               })
             )
           ),
           // Catch errors thrown above
           catchError(this.exceptionRxjs.handleRxJsError),
           finalize(() => this.store.dispatch(setLoadingSpinner({showLoading: false})))
         )
     })
   )
   ```

   })

Comment: how did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `merge` operator:

https://timdeschryver.dev/snippets#multiple-service-calls-from-an-effect

```
refresh$ = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(CustomerActions.refresh),
    exhaustMap(({ customerIds }) =>
      merge(
        ...ids.map((id) =>
          this.customersService.getCustomer(id).pipe(
            map(CustomerActions.getCustomerSuccess),
            catchError((err) =>
              of(CustomerActions.getCustomerFailed(id, err.message)),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: In your example, it is not required to wait for all requests to succeed, but in my case, I must wait for all requests to succeed before firing action. also i need to make parallel http requests